# capture=hbox inside newtcblisting doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tcolorbox

I can include a minted listing inside a tikz node using `newtcblisting` from the tcolorbox package. However, when I do that it takes all horizontal space available, because the default is to use `minipage`. So I tried to use `capture=hbox` as an option to `newtcblisting`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\definecolor{codebggray}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}

\newtcblisting{codenode}[2][]{%
  colback=codebggray,
  capture=hbox,
  listing only,
  minted options={
    fontsize=\small
  },  
  minted language=#2,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

Inside a tikz node:

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
\node(x) {
\begin{codenode}{python}
def sum (x,y):
    return x + y
\end{codenode}
};
\node(y) [below of=x]{whatever};
\draw (x) -- (y);
\end{tikzpicture}

Okay, done.

\end{document}
```

With that code, I get the following error:

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./_minted-minted-test/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
(./_minted-minted-test/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-minted-test/5274B8282787B54746A9B53E7030D876B61BC921347B2DF172485E3E034D065E.pygtex

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]

?
```

I know I can include a minipage inside the tikz node, but then, as far as I understand, I would need to include the width for each node -- and since I'm working on a 500-page document full of nodes, I'd rather only change the environment definition, not how it's used in the text.

So, is it possible to use `capture=hbox` inside `newtcblisting`?

Comment: Hope you are not getting mad at me, but: in order to answer this question (and to be sure that the answer works) you are expecting the answerer to be familiar with Ti*k*Z and tcolorbox and have pygmentize installed. You may very well find users meeting these criteria, but IMHO it would be advantageous to split the problem in smaller parts such that more users can conceivably answer. (For instance, I am concerned that putting a `tcolorbox` in a node nests `tikzpicture`s but I have no chance of checking if this has anything to do with your problem because I do not have `pygmentize` installed.)

Comment: At [this bug report](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/2), we read from the developer: *While `listings` can be put into a `\hbox` (which is used internally in your code), `minted` cannot.*

Comment: As marmot explained nesting `tikzpictures` is not a good recomendation, therefore a `tcolorbox` inside a `tikzpicture` could not be the best solution. If you explain why do you want it or what do you want to build, may be we could offer alternative constructions.

Comment: Thanks for all who answered. I realize this is not a simple thing to do; now, since I can make it work by including a minipage inside each tikz node, I'll try to get that done someiautomatically.